# Why doesn't MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI provide an accurate "Album Artist"?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I'm working with the android MediaStore. I can get a list of music on the device, and all the details associated with each media item (title, artist, duration, etc.)

I would like to be able to show a list of Albums, with their Album Artist.

To be clear, each track has an Artist, like "NoFX" but if the track occurs on a compilation CD, like Punk-O-Rama, the Artist is "NoFX" but the Album Artist would probably be something like "Various Artists."

I have reviewed the question here:

[Android - Getting Album Artist from Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392035/android-getting-album-artist-from-cursor)

and I'm trying to implement with MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST. This doesn't seem to return the correct result, however.

Looking at the Android source code, I can see there IS in fact an album_artist field behind MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, but it's flagged "@hide".
(see line ~1170 at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java).

I found this field looking through other [related] Android source code:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/apps/Development/src/com/android/development/MediaScannerActivity.java

I've written a simple app/activity to test this:

```
package com.ma.albumartisttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // query all media and get the album_artist field
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, "album_artist"}, null, null, null);

        // Store an id=>name map
        SparseArray<String> albumArtistNames = new SparseArray<String>();
        if (cursor != null) {
            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String mediaAlbumArtist = cursor.getString(1);
                if (mediaAlbumArtist != null && mediaAlbumArtist.toLowerCase().contains("various")) {
                    // loop through the cursor, save "album_artist"s that look like "various"
                    albumArtistNames.put((int) cursor.getLong(0), mediaAlbumArtist);
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        String msg;
        if (albumArtistNames.size() == 0) {
            msg = "No 'various' artists found!";
            Log.d("TESTALBUMARTIST", msg);
        } else {
            StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < albumArtistNames.size(); i++) {
                // loop through the albums found above
                int albumId = albumArtistNames.keyAt(i);
                String album_artist = albumArtistNames.get(albumId);
                Cursor albumCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST},
                        MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",
                        new String[]{"" + albumId}, null);
                if (albumCursor != null) {
                    if (albumCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        // print out what was found.
                        String artistFromAlbumsDB = albumCursor.getString(1);
                        Log.d("TESTALBUMARTIST", album_artist + ":" + artistFromAlbumsDB);
                        out.append("Album id: " + albumId).append('\n')
                                .append("Artist from media table: " + album_artist).append('\n')
                                .append("Artist from albums table: " + artistFromAlbumsDB)
                                .append("\n\n");
                    }
                    albumCursor.close();
                }
            }
            msg = out.toString();
        }

        // show the results on-screen
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(msg);
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

This activity produces the following logcat output:

```
12-20 14:16:45.688  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists:Mike Garson
12-20 14:16:45.708  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists:Franco Corelli
12-20 14:16:45.728  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists:The Foreshadowing
12-20 14:16:45.748  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists - Polyvinyl Record Co:Volcano, I'm Still Excited!!
12-20 14:16:45.778  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists - Curve Music:GRAND:PM
12-20 14:16:45.808  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists - DiN:Ian Boddy
12-20 14:16:45.828  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists:SNFU
12-20 14:16:45.858  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists:Pulley
12-20 14:16:45.878  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists:Osker
12-20 14:16:45.908  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists:Pennywise
12-20 14:16:45.938  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists:NoFX
12-20 14:16:45.958  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists:Death By Stereo
12-20 14:16:45.978  22009-22009/com.ma.albumartisttest D/TESTALBUMARTIST﹕ Various Artists (Sillage Intemporel):Sheri Malckin
```

I'm running this on a Nexus 7 running 4.4.2. I've also tested and seen the same behavior on a Huawei Prism II running 4.1.1

Why doesn't the straightforward and not "hidden" way of getting Album Artists work?

What I expect is that the Album queries also return "Various Artists".

All help is appreciated.

[image: Visual output of test Application/Activity]

Comment: What I've implemented so far is a custom Provider that queries MediaStore.Audio.Media for album_artist, and returns distinct ALBUM_IDs. It's not perfect, and performance is less than desirable (since I can't do a GROUP BY), but it looks like it's mostly working for me. It would be nice if someone knew more about why this doesn't work, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you defining or importing ListActivity anywhere in your code.

Have a look in these two examples:

- [Get info of a specified item in MediaStore.Audio.Media](http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2012/02/get-info-of-specified-item-in.html)
- [Android - Getting Album Artist from Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392035/android-getting-album-artist-from-cursor)

Comment: As mentioned above, I have thoroughly reviewed that SO link. I'm getting a valid artist name when I query the Album Artist, but it's invalid. Also, a ListActivity isn't required to query a Cursor nor to display a list -- I've used a much simpler TextView to display the results.